# How to combine DataFrames to create a new DataFrame with an additional column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a new column by combing the data from two Pandas DataFrames (DF1 and DF2). I would like to use this combined data to create a new column ("Win %") in a new DataFrame (DF3). The catch is I would like to extract only the relevant data that I am looking for. I am not sure if I need something similar to Vlookup.

I will create an example to show you what I am trying to do. Let's say I want to bet on a fighter that I think will win a tournament.

I have some fight data in DF1. The data in DF2 will also add more value so I would like to include this info as well. Ultimately I would like to create a new column in DF3 called "Win %".

Attention: I would only like DF3 to include the names from DF1 and their corresponding info.

DF1 (located below)

```
Name                      Age    Weight   Height

Chuck Norris              35       154     5'10
Bruce Lee                 30       128     5'8"
Jean Claude Van Damme     20       185     5'10"
```

DF2 (located below)

```
Name                    Win %

Rocky Balboa             .75
Arnold Schwarzenegger    .85
Bruce Lee                .99
Steven Seagal            .65
Chuck Norris             .98
Jean Claude Van Damme    .25
```

I would like the final output for DF3 to include:

1) only the names and data of the fighters in DF1 (Chuck Norris, Bruce Lee, Jean Claude Van Damme)

2) the data "Win %" from DF2 corresponding to the correct fighter.

DF3 (located below)

```
Name                      Age    Weight   Height   Win % (Win % is the new column added)

Chuck Norris              35       154     5'10     .98 (new data)
Bruce Lee                 30       128     5'8"     .99 (new data)
Jean Claude Van Damme     20       185     5'10"    .25 (new data)
```

As you can see DF3 includes the name and relevant data of the 3 fighters from DF1 and the Win % from DF2. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for any info that you many offer.

Comment: You can do `a = df2.loc[df2['Name'].isin(df1.Name)]` & then `df1.merge(a,on ='Name')`

Comment: Ty @moys! This worked like a charm =)